# Groovy script in SOAPUI to insert new tags in Soap request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using SOAP UI pro. My requirement is that, I need to write a groovy script to add few tag and elements to the previously processed request.

Below is my initial request and its name is "Certify Request" in my SOAP project

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pay="http://www.abcdefgh.com/eai/xsd/custom/Payout.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pay:request>
         <pay:header>
            <pay:applicationID>TANDEM001</pay:applicationID>
            <pay:hostname>WUNS1</pay:hostname>
            <pay:timestamp>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(new Date())}</pay:timestamp>
            <pay:correlationID>${#TestCase#CorrelationID}</pay:correlationID>
         </pay:header>

         <pay:input>
            <pay:payoutTransactionDetails>             

               <pay:transferDetails>
                  <pay:sendCountryCode>${#TestCase#sendCountryCode}</pay:sendCountryCode>
                  <pay:sendAmount>
                     <pay:currencyCode>${#TestCase#sendCurrencyCode}</pay:currencyCode>
                     <pay:value multiplier="100">${#TestCase#sendAmount}</pay:value>
                     <pay:fxRate multiplier="100">${#TestCase#senderfxRate}</pay:fxRate>

                  </pay:sendAmount>
                  <pay:receiveCountryCode>${#TestCase#receiveCountryCode}</pay:receiveCountryCode>
                  <pay:receiveAmount>
                     <pay:currencyCode>${#TestCase#receiveCurrencyCode}</pay:currencyCode>
                     <pay:value multiplier="100">${#TestCase#receiveAmount}</pay:value>
                     <pay:fxRate multiplier="100">${#TestCase#receiverfxRate}</pay:fxRate>
                  </pay:receiveAmount>
                  <pay:overallFX multiplier="100000000">${#TestCase#OverallFX}</pay:overallFX>
               </pay:transferDetails>          

            </pay:payoutTransactionDetails>
         </pay:input>
      </pay:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to add below tags in it under " "  tag:

```
 <pay:senderAgent>
                  <pay:agentID>1760289</pay:agentID>
                  <pay:accountNumber>036526952</pay:accountNumber>
               </pay:senderAgent>
```

So that my target request will be like below: (and it's name should be Initiate Request )

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pay="http://www.abcdefgh.com/eai/xsd/custom/Payout.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pay:request>
         <pay:header>
            <pay:applicationID>TANDEM001</pay:applicationID>
            <pay:hostname>WUNS1</pay:hostname>
            <pay:timestamp>${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(new Date())}</pay:timestamp>
            <pay:correlationID>${#TestCase#CorrelationID}</pay:correlationID>
         </pay:header>


         <pay:input>
            <pay:payoutTransactionDetails>

               <pay:senderAgent>
                  <pay:agentID>${#TestCase#senderAgentID}</pay:agentID>
                  <pay:accountNumber>${#TestCase#senderAgentAcountNumber}</pay:accountNumber>
               </pay:senderAgent>

               <pay:transferDetails>
                  <pay:sendCountryCode>${#TestCase#sendCountryCode}</pay:sendCountryCode>
                  <pay:sendAmount>
                     <pay:currencyCode>${#TestCase#sendCurrencyCode}</pay:currencyCode>
                     <pay:value multiplier="100">${#TestCase#sendAmount}</pay:value>
                     <pay:fxRate multiplier="100">${#TestCase#senderfxRate}</pay:fxRate>

                  </pay:sendAmount>
                  <pay:receiveCountryCode>${#TestCase#receiveCountryCode}</pay:receiveCountryCode>
                  <pay:receiveAmount>
                     <pay:currencyCode>${#TestCase#receiveCurrencyCode}</pay:currencyCode>
                     <pay:value multiplier="100">${#TestCase#receiveAmount}</pay:value>
                     <pay:fxRate multiplier="100">${#TestCase#receiverfxRate}</pay:fxRate>
                  </pay:receiveAmount>
                  <pay:overallFX multiplier="100000000">${#TestCase#OverallFX}</pay:overallFX>
               </pay:transferDetails>

            </pay:payoutTransactionDetails>
         </pay:input>
      </pay:request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I referred the solution on this link https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Pro/Using-Groovy-to-insert-new-tag-into-request-Need-help-with/m-p/124928#M28773 , however not able to succeed.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a property inside a groovy script

```
def senderAgent=" <pay:senderAgent> .......   </pay:senderAgent>" 
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Variable",senderAgent)
```

and then place that variable inside the XML

```
<pay:payoutTransactionDetails>
${#TestCase#senderAgent}
<pay:transferDetails>
```

So you have stored the xml value in groovy and then expanded that inside the XML